# Cordova (Phonegap) build undo my code changes in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova

Once I create my Phonegap project through the CLI with:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
```

add the android platform and import the project to my Eclipse, every time I run a `cordova build android` command, it undo/reverts the code that I changed on Eclipse, looks like it always gets reverted to the original project structure created by Cordova CLI, maybe I missed something in the documentation... any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Ok.. So the plan will be, I will develop my app using the root files, i.e., within hello/www/* (instead of the files within hello/platforms/android/assets/www/*) because Phonegap will override any changes to the ones for specific platforms as part of its build process. My development workflow then involves TextMate to edit HMTL/CSS/JS and then running `cordova prepare` under the project's folder in order to update the files in my Eclipse project.

Anyway.. just sharing my <strike>solution</strike> workaround to the cumbersome development process for Phonegap + Android because, IMHO, the documentation around this technology sucks...

Comment: The primary intended use case for the new cli is to avoid eclipse altogether. Create via the cli (as you have done), edit the files in `./www` as you have discovered using whatever text editor you like, then running `cordova build <platform>` to build it or `cordova emulate <platform>` to test the app on an emulator, etc. All without ever opening Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Devgeeks. I just added Eclipse to the equation so I could add the adMob libraries and change the main activity's code in a more comfortable environment, I'm not even using the Android emulator (because it's ridiculously slow), I'm using the Ripple emulator instead (however, it doesn't replace some verbose/useful info that can be found in Eclipse's "logcat" window).